# What is the usual boot time on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: boot, 16.04, lts

I've been using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) on my Thinkpad E450 for almost a year. My device usually takes over two minutes to boot.

I ran `systemd-analyze blame`, and the total boot time is 126.741 seconds with the following output:

```
21.159s dev-sda1.device
14.846s apparmor.service
10.659s snapd.service
8.515s plymouth-read-write.service
6.842s grub-common.service
6.698s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
5.585s networking.service
5.579s systemd-logind.service
5.369s gpu-manager.service
5.110s NetworkManager.service
4.961s bluetooth.service
4.533s ufw.service
4.198s console-setup.service
3.965s systemd-udevd.service
2.724s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
2.522s thermald.service
2.304s ModemManager.service
2.254s accounts-daemon.service
2.209s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
2.044s binfmt-support.service
1.718s lightdm.service
1.696s keyboard-setup.service
1.251s systemd-modules-load.service
```

Is this normal?

Comment: If you're looking to speed it up, a Solid State Drive will really help. Mine booted in as little as 10-15 seconds, after a clean install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I boot in ~12 sec but boot time bottleneck is usually the disk, with a SSD boot is much faster. So to be fair the comparison has to be done on the same hardware.

You said you're running on 16.04 but what's your kernel? A new kernel usually boots faster. Check with `uname -a` and if you're still on 4.4 upgrade your kernel by activating [HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack). This is [how-to](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_-_Xenial_Xerus).

Comment: Thank you for offering to help! The output for uname -a is:                   Linux Enchiridion 4.4.0-96-generic #119-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 12 14:59:54 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: So yes, you can upgrade your kernel using the second link in my answer.

Comment: This seems to have worked. Boot time is only about a minute or less now. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can mark that answer as the good answer then.

Answer (score 5):

The boot time depends on several parameters:

1. The HW of your computer

   - CPU
   - Disk (SSD?)
   - RAM
2. The software installed on your computer.

   - Please share the output of `systemd-analyze blame` so we'll be able to help you identify if there are some un-needed software which can be removed/updated which will reduce the boot time

Comment: Thank you for offering to help out. My laptop has a core i3 processor with 4GB RAM, 500MB internal storage.

Comment: @AvikBanerjee - please [edit] your question, and add the output of ` systemd-analyze blame` to your question.

Answer (score -2):

It depends mainly on the **BIOS** system, including your **motherboard**, also the power of your **CPU** and how the installation of the OS was made.

Two minutes is inside the "normal" or acceptable booting time, but you could look for some techniques in Google for improving that time. (For example, look for how to suspend your computer when shutting down).

Comment: I don't see how this helps the OP.